# Authentication function not working - CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have the below code to authenticate user to the application. I have been able to register a user on the system but my authentication code cannot redirect user in to the application after trying to login with the right details.  The page only redirects the user back to the login page even though  i am using the right user details.

**Controller**

```
var $salt = '%&)#$sfsf(abm@009011';

 function authenticate() {

    $username = $this->input->post('username');

    $this->db->where('phone', $username);
    $password =  $this->db->where('password', md5(crypt($this->input->post('password'), $this->salt)));
    $query = $this->db->get('user_login');        
    if ($query->num_rows = 1) {
        //echo "success";
         return true;
    } else
        return false;
    }
```

What else could i be doing wrong in code ? 
PS: Beginner with CodeIgniter

Comment: Very hard to tell what's wrong (besides using assignment operators instead of comparison operators) without seeing some more code. You are just returning a true/false value, but we have no clue what you're doing with it afterwards. Are you spawning a session with the logged in user data? are your controllers checking that data to "decide" if they let you access their methods? Also, I'd strongly suggest changing the very insecure way you chose to hash passwords (use password_hash instead of the crypt+md5+static salt which is actually as insecure as it gets)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are assigning not comparing, you should use `==` instead of `=`

```
if ($query->num_rows == 1) {
}
```

Comment: Okay..Thanks but i am still not able to get redirected into the application. It redirects me back to the login page

Comment: print query and check all the thing are gone right as per you expect.

Comment: when i print `query`, i don't get any results returned but i get `1` when i echo `$query->num_rows` before the `if()` statement

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `var` and use `==` to compare values in the `if()` statement

```
$salt = '%&)#$sfsf(abm@009011';

 function authenticate() {

    $username = $this->input->post('username');

    $this->db->where('phone', $username);
    $password =  $this->db->where('password', md5(crypt($this->input->post('password'), $this->salt)));
    $query = $this->db->get('user_login');        
    if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
        //echo "success";
         return true;
    } else
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Okay..Thanks but i am still not able to get redirected into the application. It redirects me back to the login page

Comment: what is the result of this `echo $query->num_rows` before `if()` statement?

Comment: The results is `1`

Comment: @RoboPHP it should be `$query->num_rows()` not `$query->num_rows`

Comment: Okay, if your directly posting your data, I mean you are not calling the function from ajax then you can use: redirect('Your controller name') instead of return true statement;

Comment: Even after replacing with `redirect('Your controller name')`, it is still the same issue happening

Comment: have you put your controller's name in place of 'Your controller name'?